# Playing macros in a row (notepad++)

Tags: notepad++

Since I found people asking questions about notepad++ on here when I was asking google for a solution for this problem, I will try if anyone here can help me. :)

I have a files that need to go through the same thing everyday. I made myself macros to speed things up.

**Is there a way so execute multiple macros in a row?**

Example - I open a file by hand and start a macro which triggers a specific macro after the one before it finished:

1. Macro A (only execute)
2. Macro B (repeat until end of the file is reached)
3. Macro C (repeat until end of the file is reached)
4. Macro D (only execute)
5. ...

Between every macro, the cursor should jump to the first line's first place.

Is this possible in Notepad++?

If so: Would it also be possible to execute this on every opened document at once?

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

> My first thought was to create a super macro which concatenates all
>     the individual macros.
>   Unfortunately the "Run a Macro Multiple Times" command for macros B & C
>     can't be executed from within a macro, otherwise the process would be:
>
> Create a macro for Ctrl+Home so you can see what code to put before each
>     macro.
>   Make sure the Box Tree view is set for editing
>   `Settings` `Preferences` `Editing` `Folder Margin Style = Box tree`
>   Take a copy of shortcuts.xml. Call it shortcuts-Copy.xml
>   On my machine it is located in C:\Users\Chris G\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\
>   Edit shortcuts-Copy.xml.
>   Alt+0 collapses all the code making it easier to see the list of macro
>       names.
>   Merge all the macros into one by removing the lines between the macros...

```
 </Macro>  
 <Macro name="Macro B" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">  
 :
 </Macro>
 <Macro name="Macro C" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
 :
```

> Exit Notepad++
>   Rename shortcuts.xml  shortcuts-orig.xml
>   Rename shortcuts-Copy.xml  shortcuts.xml
>   Run Notepad++. The new big macro will be in the macro list.
>
> If you can't re code macros B & C so they don't need to be run with "Run a
>     Macro Multiple Times" you will have to install something like a python
>     plugin and use that to execute all the macros.
>     Unfortunately that is more work.
>
> Sorry I can't give a simple solution.
>   Chris G.